# How to add ng-repeat item to an array

Tags: arrays, angularjs, json, this

I am building a shopping cart which I am using ng-repeat to iterate through a list of JSON objects. I created a function addToBag which I would like to push the object into an empty array which I will use to display items on my shopping cart checkout page. I am having trouble accessing self variable.

```
app.controller('shoppingController', function($scope, NgTableParams){
            var self = this;
            $scope.shoppingCart = [];
            $scope.shoppingItemCount = 0;
            $scope.total = 0;
            $scope.addToBag = function(quantity){
            quantity = parseInt(quantity);
            $scope.shoppingItemCount = $scope.shoppingItemCount + quantity;
                $scope.shoppingCart.push(self.item);
                console.log($scope.shoppingCart);

            };
});

 <tr ng-repeat="item in $data" ng-model="item.data">
   <form>
      <td title="'Search By Category'" filter="{ categories: 'text'}" sortable="'categories'">
        <img ng-src="{{item.imageUrl}}">
      </td>

      <td title="'Search by Name'" filter="{ name: 'text'}" sortable="'name'">
        <ul>
          <li><h1> {{item.name}}</h1></li>
          <li ng-model="price"><strong>Price:</strong> {{item.price | nfcurrency }}</li>
          <li><strong>Caffeine Scale:</strong>  {{item.caffeineScale}}</li>
          <li><strong>Rating:</strong> {{item.rating}}</li>
          <li><strong>In Stock?:</strong>      {{item.inStock | true_false}}</li>
          <li><strong>Categories:</strong>
            <ul ng-repeat="category in item.categories">
              <li>{{category}}</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </td>

      <td title="'Sort By Price'"sortable="'price'">
       <ul>
         <li>Quantity:
          <select class="form-control" ng-model="quantity">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>
          </select>
          <input class="btn btn-success addbag" type="submit" ng-click="addToBag(quantity)"
           value="Add To Bag">
      </ul>

    </td>


</form>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of only add the quantity as parameter for the *addToBag* function, you can try to pass the *item* too :

```
 <input class="btn btn-success addbag" type="submit" ng-click="addToBag(quantity,item)"
       value="Add To Bag">
```

And the function *$scope.addToBag* will be like :

```
$scope.addToBag = function(quantity, newItem){
        quantity = parseInt(quantity);
        $scope.shoppingItemCount = $scope.shoppingItemCount + quantity;
        $scope.shoppingCart.push(newItem);
        console.log($scope.shoppingCart);
};
```

Comment: Great! Worked fine. Thanks